# Prove that two simple graphs on 4 vertices are isomorphic if and only if they have the same degree sequence.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

The possible degree sequence of the simple graph with 4 vertices is $(0,0,0,0)$ or $(0,0,1,1)$ or $(1,1,1,1)$ or $(0,1,1,2)$ or $(0,2,2,2)$ or $(1,1,2,2)$. Then I do not understand how to prove the given question. Anyone, please help me .

Comment: An isomorphism of graphs is a bijection on the vertices *and* on the edges in a way that's compatible. The degree sequence limits the possibilities for how to identify vertices (degrees have to match), so you have to argue in each case that the edges are completely determined by this choice.

Comment: Note: this result is only possible because $|V|=4$ is so small. It might help to look at a pair of [non-isomorphic graphs](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) that nonetheless have the same degree sequence. Unsurprisingly, they have more than $4$ vertices.

Answer (score 1):

All the $0$'s can be ignored since they will correspond to isolated vertices and isolated vertices are always isomorphic.

Same for the $3$'s, those will be vertices connected to all other vertices.

This means all vertices with degree $0$ or $3$ can be removed from the graph without changing the question.

What you are left with is either two disjunct linegraphs of length $2$ or one linegraph that is completely determined by the degree sequence.